# how to create post with different user type (two foreign key for one post model)?

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

i'm working on a project the scenario : `teacher`s can make course and publish it in `Course` model and also institute can make course in `Course` model?
how can i make it automatically choose one of the `foreign key` fields? 
both institutes and teacher can have post

```
class Institute(models.Model):
    courses = GenericRelation(Course)
    institute_name = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institute_id = models.SlugField(unique=True,default=slug_generator(),blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    locations  = models.OneToOneField(Location,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default='')
    institute_name.is_institute = True
    pass...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.institute_name.username

class Teacher(models.Model):
    course = GenericRelation(Course)
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,default=slug_generator())
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11,default='')
    teacher.is_teacher = True
    certification = models.ForeignKey(Certification,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher.username

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_institute = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username



class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student.is_student = True
    student_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,default=slug_generator())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.username
```

Then define:

```py
if user loggedin in  user.is_institute
```

So querying in institute model

```
else loggedin in user.is_teacher
```

And then will work on teacher model. 
Does this structure fine ?

I've heard that `generic foreign keys` not working with API
i also tried this , but i dont how to query them

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    time_created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


Teacher ,Institute have different fields name
```

Thanks

Comment: so what is the solution for these types of projects ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that GenericRelation is something you really need for this.

How about change the structure a little bit. Let's have `Course` as the main model for the task.

For example

```
class Course(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    # other necessary fields

    @property
    def is_teacher(self):
        return self.teacher is not None

    @property
    def is_institute(self):
        return self.institute is not None
```

After that you can check if `Course` is made by institute like

`if course_object.is_teacher:`

But if you really want to differentiate your users by institute or teacher you'd need to make custom user model, here's the starting point for you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

In that case in your `Course` model you'd have only one field something like `author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Hope I've got your question right.